# Постановка запятой в предложении?

Tags: запятые, сложное-предложение

Нужна ли запятая в предложениях перед союзом "и"?

> Секунда и я буду просыпаться.
>
> Еще одно мгновение и я уеду.

Answer (score 3):

**Лучше в обоих предложениях использовать тире.**

Из Розенталя:

**§ 32…**

2. Если первая часть сложносочиненного предложения или обе части являются односоставными номинативными (или назывными) предложениями, между частями, как правило, ставится **тире**: *Ещё напор — **и** враг бежит (П.); Ещё одна минута объяснения — **и** давнишняя вражда готова была погаснуть (Г.); Вот крик — **и** снова всё вокруг затихло (Л.); Ещё несколько слов, несколько ласк от матери — **и** крепкий сон овладел мною (Акс.); Ещё единый миг — **и** я паду к её ногам (А. К. Т.); Пятнадцать лет такой работы — **и** машина человеческого организма вся разбита (Г.‑М.); Мгновение — **и** всё опять тонуло во мраке (Кор.); …Неверное движение руки — **и** машина дробит вам кости (М. Г.); Треск разрываемой рубахи — **и** Гаврила лежал на песке (Ж. Г.); Один прыжок — **и** лев уже на спине буйвола (Купр.); Ещё год, два — **и** старость… (Эр.); Один шаг, один весёлый шаг — **и** открывается вольная жизнь, прозрачная, как воздух, бесконечность! (Фед.); Улыбка маленькой дочки, солнечные блики на морозных окнах, удачно подрумяненные хлебы — **и** вот она уже светится, поёт своим тоненьким трепещущим голоском, замешивая пойло коровам (Ник.); Сухой треск ракетницы — **и** в небе вспыхивают два рассыпчатых зелёных огня (Перв.); Полчаса на отдых — **и** опять за работу!; Ещё дня два-три — **и** все разъедутся по своим домам.*

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=135#pp135